# C++ equal, not equal,

Tags: c++

I'm looking for the opposite to

```
std::equal
```

so I'm looking for not equal to. I have tried

```
std::not_equal_to
```

and

```
std::!equal
```

none of which appear to be working? Thanks chaps.

Answer (score 11):

you are applying the operator wrong. use it like

```
!std::equal
```